# Determining the Greens function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, coherent-states

I understand the basics of greens function. But here in this paper, i am not able to understand how have they solved for the Greens function. In particular, I don't get what $G_{R}$ and $G_{A}$ are.Also, how have they, at the end used the S matrix is also not clear. Kindly help. [image]

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper?

Comment: Coherent states and the forced quantum oscillator by P. Carruthers and  M. M. Nieto

Comment: I think $G_R$ and $G_A$ refers to the retarded (i.e. causal) and advanced green's functions. Try to Fourier-transform eq. (4.8) and solve for $G(\omega)$ (the Fourier transform of $G(t)$). In signal processing language $G_R(t)$ is also called the impulse response. Check the "example" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green.27s_functions

Comment: You seem to asking how the author got from equation (4.8) to (4.9) and (4.10).  This is a pretty standard diff eq and the Gree's function for it (and method to solve) can be found in almost any diff eq text.  I am sure you will find it in Morse and Feshbach Methods of Theoretical Physics.